# Exception - Cannot invoke "org.apache.axis2.jaxws.core.controller.InvocationControllerFactory.getInvocationController()" because "icf" is null

Tags: java-17

Our application is a gradle project using java11 and spring boot 2.7.11 version and involves some calls to a soap service. For calling soap service we have written a wsimport task to generate stub classes using wsdl.
Now we are trying to upgrade our application to Java-17.There are no compile issues during upgrade but the calls to soap service are failing with the above exception.
Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

I am not able to understand what exactly is causing issue

Comment: Check how `icf` is initialized and consider under which circumstances the initializer expression can evaluate to `null`. We can’t do that for you.